# make Custom QWidget selectable

Tags: qt, qwidget

I'm working on a boardgame and I'm trying to make QWidgets (Rectangles) selectable.
So I have a BoardView (inherited from QWidget) which contains BuildingViews, PlantationViews (both inherited from QWidget). It all shows up on the window, but it is not clickable. How can I make this clickable?

Comment: Are you trying to move these widgets with your mouse? You can override mouse events to move widgets, but I will have to ask, why are you using `QWidget`s instead of `QGraphicsItem`s?

Comment: My professor said QWidgets were the one to use. I'm not going to switch to QGraphicsItems. I do not want to move these widgets, just selecting them.

Comment: All QWidgets are clickable. I think your question is badly phrased. What have you tried and what is it that you want?

Comment: I'd like to save the last clicked (selected) QWidget, so that it is later passed on in a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to make a QMouseEvent implementation where the widget ID is forwarded,
something like this:

In the implementation of your widget (e.g. YourWidget.cpp):

```
YourWidget::MouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
     emit clickedWithMouse(this);    // this is a signal, declared in YourWidget.h
}
```

In the "main" game file (e.g. Game.cpp):

```
Game::onButtonClicked(YourWidget* widget)    // this is a public slot, you must connect all YourWidgets's clickedWithMouse signals to this slot (in Game object code, e.g. when initialising the board)
{
    lastWidget = widget; //save the widget "ID" (lastWidget is a member of class Game)
    someFunction(widget); //do something with the widget (if you wish)
}
```